# How to make difference between email html body and html attachment in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, email-attachments, email-parsing

I use `email.message.Message` object to operate email message and need to extract only html attachment, while message can have html body, so looks like  `get_content_type()` makes no sense here.

Is there any simple way in python to determine if it is body part or attachment?

**UPD:**

Simplified former function looks like this:

```
def get_attachments(mail):            
    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() in ('application/pdf', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'):
            yield part
```

Comment: Could you show us what you did so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was much easier than I expected:

```
def get_attachments(mail):            
    for part in mail.walk():
        disposition = part.get('Content-Disposition')
        if disposition and 'attachment' in disposition:
            yield part
```

Comment: Was looking at the same problem today. Your solution is correct, but can be written shorter. Consider: if part.get('Content-Disposition', '').startswith('attachment')